# Windows azure webapp with spatial data

Tags: .net, azure, azure-sql-database, geospatial

Exploring windows azure atm for a weekend project involving storing location data.

What is the best way to be able to store and process spatial data on windows azure using .net ?

Is processing spatial data (like doing intersect on either geometry or geography, and calculating distances) good enough yet?

(Was interested of using django on azure, until i found that geodjango does not support sql server. 
I am not really interested to maintain my own database vm, prefer microsoft to do it for me)